# Error in displaying fragment in view pager (PagerTabStrip) when going to another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment called projectFragment that contains ViewPager and a button called plusButton that take us to another fragment .In this ViewPager I used PagerTabStrip.I have 3 tabs.In each tabs I have listView. When I run my code it worked and showing listViewes and works clean.

**the problem is here:**
When I click plusButton and go to another fragment and press back to come back to projectFragment, listViewes doesn't show.
I should close the app and restart it to show it.
any body can help me?????

this code is for switching between fragments:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    String[] titles = {"کار های من", "پیشنهادهای ارسالی", "پروژه های موجود"};

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return MyWorksFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return SentBidsFragment.newInstance(1);
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return ExistProjectsFragment.newInstance(2);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }

}
```

Comment: Can u share your code how u are opening new fragment

Comment: I added my code